# Optimal (or at least close to) license pool

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-optimization

I am struggling once again with a question. But this time I want to try to answer it properly: It is to decide, what licenses to buy for a software product.

We have a software product, which has two license types

1. A license, which may only be used by one person. It costs x.
2. A floating license, which may only be used by one person at a time, but immediately after the person releases the license, someone else can use it. It costs 4x

Now given that I have a certain amount of people each with a different usage profile of the software product. Some use it almost daily and some almost never. How can I calculate the number of licenses of type 1 and type 2 to buy? I will probably not be able to serve all people unless everyone gets its individual license. So I probably have to say that I want the amount of licenses that in 99% of the time a user can use the product, when he wants to. And of course I want to minimize the cost :-)

What additional information would I need to collect from the users?

I tried to abstract my problem and came up with "resource allocation". However, even with that term I was not able to find a suitable way to the solution.

Can someone here point me in the right direction or maybe even provide a solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need a lot more information to estimate this. In particular, you need the set of user profiles: for each user, the probability that they want the license as a function of the time of day. If you really want 99% availablity you probably want individual licenses for heavy users and group for the rest. I doubt there's an algorithm. You could simulate this.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Thank you very much for the comment. I added the question on the information to collect. Your solution sounds reasonable. But the questions are: what defines a "heavy user" and how many other users could I serve per floating license.

Comment: You don't need a binary distinction between "heavy"and "light" users. You need actual user profiles with time dependent probability of wanting access.

Comment: Even people who use the software daily probably do not use it all the time.  If you really want to minimize the cost you have to beat on people to log out whenever they are not actively using it.  Particularly for your occasional users, how bad is it if they have to wait a while and try again later?  Is there a time of day when everybody wants access?  If it is scheduling software, everybody might want to log in first thing in the morning to check the day's schedule.

Comment: A simpleminded approach, which might or might not work is to estimate each user's percentage of time using the software.  If the demands are independent and uniformly distributed you can use a normal approximation to the number of simultaneous users and buy mean plus two (or three) sigma floating licenses.  This is a good example of assuming a normal distribution because we know how to calculate with it even though it may not reflect reality.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thank you for the suggestion with the normal distribution. I was already thinking in a similar direction, but with Poisson. But as I am not sure, which distribution would be the right choice, I rather asked.

Comment: @EthanBolker: You said in an earlier comment, that you doubt there's an algorithm. I doubt that ;-) For this problem seems to occur quite often and there should be a solution - even if it is just a heuristic. How much servers do I need to satisfy x requests per hour? How much employees does my call center need to handle a certain amount of calls? These should be similar questions to mine (despite the difference with the individual license for heavy users)

Comment: @Gunter This is indeed a serious problem in resource provisioning and there is lots of mathematics (queuing theory) addressing it. But there is no analyzable heuristic for your particular problem until you specify it in a lot more mathematical detail.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Thank you for pointing me to queuing theory. I will look into this. I am currently not really able to specify my problem in more mathematical detail, because I have no idea what information is needed. Thus, I kept it as abstract as possible.